# ¿Cómo aplicar una función a cada elemento de una lista en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una lista con 82 elementos, cada elemento de la lista contiene una columna llamada "Media movil PM10", y quisiera aplicar la función `filter` en esta columna, para todos los elementos de la lista,  para que me filtre aquellos valores que superen el valor 50.

He estado intentando con la función lapply, pero no he podido generar un código que funcione.

`Prueba<- lapply(X=Mediamovil2010, FUN= function(x){filter(x,file = paste0(filter(x$MediamovilPM10[1], '>50')`

A continuación, una muestra de los datos:

```
$ MOVILING_RochePM10.csv                                :Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2191 obs. of  26 variables:
..$ X1                : num [1:2191] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
..$ Unnamed: 0        : num [1:2191] 357271 357272 357273 357274 357275 ...
..$ rowid             : num [1:2191] 3083119 3083120 3083121 3083122 3083123 ...
..$ date              : chr [1:2191] "1999-01-01" "1999-01-02" "1999-01-03" "1999-01-04" ...
..$ site              : chr [1:2191] "ROCHE (PM-10)" "ROCHE (PM-10)" "ROCHE (PM-10)" "ROCHE (PM-10)" ...
..$ EnvAut            : chr [1:2191] "CORPOGUAJIRA - CAR DE LA GUAJIRA" "CORPOGUAJIRA - CAR DE LA GUAJIRA" "CORPOGUAJIRA - CAR DE LA GUAJIRA" "CORPOGUAJIRA - CAR DE LA GUAJIRA" ...
..$ Latitude          : num [1:2191] 11.1 11.1 11.1 11.1 11.1 ...
..$ Longitude         : num [1:2191] -72.6 -72.6 -72.6 -72.6 -72.6 ...
..$ AveragingTimeHours: num [1:2191] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 ...
..$ Year              : num [1:2191] 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 ...
..$ Units             : chr [1:2191] "ugm3" "ugm3" "ugm3" "ugm3" ...
..$ COD_DEP           : num [1:2191] 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 ...
..$ NOM_DEP           : chr [1:2191] "La Guajira" "La Guajira" "La Guajira" "La Guajira" ...
..$ COD_MUN           : num [1:2191] 44078 44078 44078 44078 44078 ...
..$ NOM_MUN           : chr [1:2191] "Barrancas" "Barrancas" "Barrancas" "Barrancas" ...
..$ StationType       : chr [1:2191] "Fija" "Fija" "Fija" "Fija" ...
..$ CO                : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ NO                : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ NO2               : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ O3                : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ PM10              : num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ PM2.5             : num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ PST               : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ SO2               : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ Media movil PM10  : num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ Media movil PM2.5 : num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..- attr(*, "spec")=List of 3
.. ..$ cols   :List of 26
.. .. ..$ X1                : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Unnamed: 0        : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ rowid             : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ date              : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ site              : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ EnvAut            : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Latitude          : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Longitude         : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ AveragingTimeHours: list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Year              : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Units             : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ COD_DEP           : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ NOM_DEP           : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ COD_MUN           : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ NOM_MUN           : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ StationType       : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ CO                : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
.. .. ..$ NO                : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
.. .. ..$ NO2               : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
.. .. ..$ O3                : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
.. .. ..$ PM10              : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
.. .. ..$ PM2.5             : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
.. .. ..$ PST               : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
.. .. ..$ SO2               : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Media movil PM10  : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Media movil PM2.5 : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
.. ..$ default: list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_guess" "collector"
.. ..$ skip   : num 1
.. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "col_spec"
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar datos de ejemplo de la lista que mencionas y de lo que espera obtener?. ¿La lista se llama `Mediamovil2010` ? En el código faltan varios paréntisis y el corchete que cierra la función

Comment: Laura, si cada elemento es un data.frame y lo que buscas es filtrar sus filas, entiendo que esto `Prueba <- lapply(X = Mediamovil2010, FUN  = function(x){x[x$MediamovilPM10 > 50,]})` podría servir. Sino, te sugiero que armes un ejemplo, mínimo de los datos.

Comment: ¡Hola Patricio! Cada elemento es un data.frame. He intentado con el código que me sugeriste, me crea una lista con el nombre "prueba" pero con los mismos datos de la lista original, es decir que no está filtrando los datos mayores a 50. ¿Cómo podría compartirles un ejemplo de los datos? Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Hola @LauraR, en principio, agrega a tu pregunta la salida de `str(Mediamovil2010)` eso nos va a dar una idea de como son los datos.

Comment: Hola Patricio, ya he editado la pregunta con la muestra de los datos, espero eso pueda ayudar. ¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: @LauraR, lo que muestras pareciera un simple `data.frame`, con la única dificultad en el nombre desnormalizado de la variable, podrías hacer algo así: `filter(MOVILING_RochePM10.csv, ``Media movil PM10`` > 50)`, nota los bakticks para encerrar el nombre de variable que tiene espacios. Si lo que muestras es uno de los elementos de una lista, mi propuesta anterior debiera funcionarte, salvo por el tema del nombre de variable `Prueba <- lapply(X = MOVILING_RochePM10.csv, FUN  = function(x){x[x$``Media movil PM10`` > 50,]})`.

Comment: En el comentario anterior ves dobles backticks por temas de formato, pero es uno solo.

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias Patricio! Ya me ha funcionado.

Comment: Me alegro @LauraR, ¿era entonces el problema con el nombre con espacios? si es así después dejo la respuesta así queda la idea. Saludos.

Comment: Sí señor, creo que el problema era el nombre con espacios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los nombres de variables no estándar, suelen traer problemas, si bien es posible definir el nombre de una columna como `Media movil PM10`, la forma luego de acceder por nombre tiene sus bemoles. Si el objeto es un simple `data.frame` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
map(Mediamovil2010, ~filter(.x, `Media movil PM10` > 50))
```

Nota los "backticks" para encerrar el nombre desnormalizado (con espacios), En R base:

```
lapply(Mediamovil2010, function(x) x[which(x[, "Media movil PM10"]>50),] )
```

Comment: ¡Hola Patricio, estuve realizando el filtro de algunas listas con el código que me has recomendado, sin embargo, me genera muchas filas de NA. Quisiera saber si es posible generar un filtro con el cual me deje solamente las filas con el parámetro que le estoy pidiendo, y si no cumple, que me deje 0 filas, muchas gracias!

Comment: @LauraR, el `filter` solo te deja las filas que cumplan con la condición especificada en la variable que estás filtrando. No puede dejarte valores `NA` en dicha variable si estás filtrando por valores mayores a 50, debe ser otra problema, pero necesitaría ver los datos.

Comment: Has aplicado bien el `filter` a cada objeto de la lista? prueba con `map(Mediamovil2010, filter, "Media movil PM10" > 50)`

Comment: Sí señor, he aplicado el filter a cada elemento de la lista. He intentado con el código que me has recomendado, pero me genera un "List of length 82" es decir, no me genera elementos que pueda ver por separado. Tal vez deba eliminar los NA que se me generan? Si es así, cómo podria hacerlo? ¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: ¿`Mediamovil2010` es una lista donde cada elemento es un `data.frame`? si es así, el código de mi comentario, te debería retornar la misma lista, solo que cada `data.frame` debería tener menos filas por que justamente estas aplicando un filtro. ¿Quieres esto o un único `data.frame` que consolide todos los datos?

Comment: Buenas Tardes Patricio, mi intención es generar un filtro que elimine las filas que no coincidan, generándome una nueva lista con menos filas. No obstante, me sale una lista con casi la misma cantidad de filas, en el que las filas de la columna 0 las llama, NA, NA.1, NA.2, y así sucesivamente. Hay casos en los que sólo cumplen 4 filas y me salen 365 filas, 4 con datos y el resto con NAs.

Comment: Me es difícil ayudarte sin ver los datos, si pudieras compartir `Mediamovil2010` de alguna forma, lo miro un poco.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Patricio, tal vez por algún correo podría compartir el R.data?

Comment: En mi perfil esta mi correo, sino podes usar algún servicio de hosting anonimo temporal tipo: https://www.file.io/

Comment: @LauraR, prueba esto que es R base: `lapply(Mediamovil2010, function(x) x[which(x[, "Media movil PM10"]>50),] ) -> salida`.

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias Patricio! Ahora sí genera solamente las filas que corresponden.

Comment: Me alegro. Por cierto, con `filter` sería `map(Mediamovil2010, ~filter(.x, `Media movil PM10` > 50)) `. Saludos